# sails on stop server event

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm creating connections to different services like solr, elastic search in **bootstrap.js**:

```
    sails.solr = require('solr-client').createClient(
          ....
    );

   sails.elasticClient = new require('elasticsearch').Client({
          ....
   });
```

And use this connection in application:

```
var client = sails.solr;
var query = client.createQuery().q({
  ....
})
```

Now how will I close this connections on sails server shutdown.

I tried this event in **app.js** but it never gets called.

```
 sails.on('lower', function(){
      sails.log.debug('Shutting down sails..');
  });
```

node version: v0.12.7
sails version: 0.11.0

Also is this a good idea to create connection on boot & reuse it for all the requests or create new connection and close it as and when required.